# How do I merge two Reactive Cocoa commands?

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I'm making 2 network calls (Case Details, and Message Details). I'd like to merge both RACCommands so they both complete and then I call nextMethod().

Here are the two calls working independently from each other:

```
@weakify(self);
[[self.loadCaseCommand.executionSignals switchToLatest] subscribeNext:^(MZACaseDetails *caseDetails) {
    @strongify(self);
    self.caseDetails = caseDetails;
    self.watcherAccessLevel = caseDetails.watcherAccessLevel;
    self.mutableCaseDetails = (MZAMutableCaseDetails *)[self.caseDetails mutableCopy];

    [self createViewModels];
    [(RACSubject *)self.contentDidChangeSignal sendNext:nil];
}];

[[self.loadMessagesCommand.executionSignals switchToLatest] subscribeNext:^(MZAMessage *messageDetails) {
    @strongify(self);
    self.messageDetails = messageDetails;
}];
```

Comment: Why do you use `RACCommand` instead just a `RACSignal` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two or more RACSignal and want to combine them to one which sendNext: when all input sendNext: and sendError: when one send error you should use zip operator.

http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html

in reactive cocoa it looks like

```
RACSignal* signal1 = [self.loadCaseCommand.executionSignals switchToLatest];
RACSignal* signal2 = [self.loadMessagesCommand.executionSignals switchToLatest];

[RACSignal zip:@[signal1, signal2]] subscribeNext:^(RACTuple *data)
{
    RACTupleUnpack(MZACaseDetails *caseDetails, MZAMessage *messageDetails) = data;
    //...
}
```